# How to get strings in SQL Table, which are top1 or top3

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

That's code + result
I was trying different ways, but still don't know how to get from this TOP 1 or TOP 3 by CNT.

Result should look like 
Abon№5   -  800, for top1 and same for top 3

That's code:

```
select a.c_name as abonentname, count(*) as cnt
from st_abonents a
inner join qry_type qt on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref
inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
group by a.c_name
order by cnt;
```

And result

[image: QUES]

What should I add to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you normally do this with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select a.c_name as abonentname, count(*) as cnt
      from st_abonents a inner join
           qry_type qt
           on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref inner join
           qry_queue qq
           on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
      group by a.c_name
      order by cnt
     ) t
where rownum <= 3;
```

In the most recent version of Oracle, you can do:

```
      select a.c_name as abonentname, count(*) as cnt
      from st_abonents a inner join
           qry_type qt
           on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref inner join
           qry_queue qq
           on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
      group by a.c_name
      order by cnt
      fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Comment: it works only for numbers of rows, but I found solution
+ to your code I did sorting. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
select Top(3) a.c_name as abonentname, count(*) as cnt
from st_abonents a
inner join qry_type qt on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref
inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
group by a.c_name
order by cnt DESC;
```